# Planning huge SharePoint libraries in a site collection

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search, sharepoint-library

I am working on creating a POC for a huge SharePoint site. The site is actually a seperate site collection that holds 2-3 document libraries. These document libraries are expected to grow rapidly in size and reach a size of 100000 documents in next 2 years (documents are all images of size 3-5MB). I have following questions. If somebody got some experience please share some suggestions.

1. As the content grows, will there be a performance impact with the
   custom search/filter webparts that uses CAML and SPQuery?
2. Is there any better alternative to CAML such as Search API to return items from libraries?

Our end users access these libraries only through custom webparts, not through native SP views.

Thanks in advance
-Arun

Comment: You should look into SharePoint list and library thresholds. CAML is the fastest besides SQL to fetch data from lists and libraries in SharePoint, so stick to CAML is my advice.

Comment: could you specify what SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: It's SharePoint 2010 Enterprise

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint has some [boundaries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx) like

- Boundaries: Static limits that cannot be exceeded by design
- Thresholds: Configurable limits that can be exceeded to accommodate
  specific requirements
- Supported limits: Configurable limits that have
  been set by default to a tested value

For more information see the [best practise](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx) for designing large lists

Answer (score 2):

Before making any recommendations you should review SharePoint 2010 best practices for Search erformance. Articles like this one (even though they were written in the beta timeframe) hold valuable insight into large list/library handling. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/enterprisesearch/archive/2010/06/09/sharepoint-2010-search-dogfood-part-3-query-performance-optimization.aspx

Using Query is always going to be faster that any other approach. The only issue is "freshness" of the index. This means ensuring that you are configuring search to crawl the corpus to keep the index fresh. Whether you chose query (and which query syntax you choose) over another approach will also be determined by how you are creating your search experience for your end users.

Note that in SharePoint 2013 the Search.asmx and SQL Query Language approaches are depricated in favor of REST and Keyword Query Language. So if you are planning on implementing a SharePoint 2013 Search farm anytime soon, that may drive your decision. Note that you can implement SharePoint 2013 Search against 2010 farms and gain the advantages of Continuous Crawling and significantly improved search experience without having to upgrade your 2010 site collections.

BTW, 100,000 is not that "huge" particularly for images, which tend to be slim on metadata. You generally plan additional index partitions at 10M documents. Are you planning to employ a custom iFilter to handle the image metadata or just go with the out of the box null filter?

Comment: Thank you Mathew for the suggestions. As you correctly mentioned, the image libraries that we are planning don't have much meta data associated. Also we have to show the documents available in the search results as soon as they get uploaded. With around 50,000 images uploaded and an index on "Title" column, I am able to run CAML queries without any performance issues. With your recomandations I will continue to work on my POC to identify the best possible solution for us.

Comment: You should also look at 2013 Continuous Crawling. It's built for keeping indexes significantly fresher than 2010.